# How can i get geofence event in a foreground service

Tags: android, kotlin

it is my first time using maps sdk and i am having a lot of trouble to learn how to use it. I am creating an application which will send user's location to backend for each significant displacement, and a choose to use geofence to do it.

I built a foreground to detect when the user moves, even when his application is not open, but i can't get any event through the broadcast, even the initial trigger it cant hear, i am testing manually using fake gps app.

foreground service:

```
class LocationForegroundService : Service() {

    private lateinit var geofencingClient: GeofencingClient
    private lateinit var locationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    val trackingWorking: Boolean get() = geoAlreadyInitialized

    private val pendingBroadcastIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
        val intent = Intent(this, GeofenceReceiver::class.java)
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this,
            0,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )
    }

    companion object {
        private var geoAlreadyInitialized = false
        private const val GEOFENCE_ID = "rider_location"
        private const val TRACKING_CHANNEL = "tracking_channel"
        private const val TRACKING_NOTIFICATION_ID = 1
        private var count = 0
        fun startService(context: Context) {
            val startIntent = Intent(context, LocationForegroundService::class.java)
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, startIntent)
        }

        fun stopService(context: Context) {
            val stopIntent = Intent(context, LocationForegroundService::class.java)
            context.stopService(stopIntent)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        locationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        geofencingClient = LocationServices.getGeofencingClient(this)
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        ...
        getLastLocation()
        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun getLastLocation() {
        if (geoAlreadyInitialized) geofencingClient.removeGeofences(pendingBroadcastIntent)
        locationClient.lastLocation
            .addOnSuccessListener { location ->
                createGeofence(location)
                ++count
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                print("fail")
                // TODO WHEN NOTIFICATION IS BIND TO THE FRAGMENT SET TO PAUSE
            }
    }

    private fun createGeofence(location: Location) {
        val geofence = getGeofence(location)

        val geofencingRequest = getGeofenceRequest(geofence)

        createGeofenceEventListeners(geofencingRequest)
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun createGeofenceEventListeners(geofencingRequest: GeofencingRequest) {
        geofencingClient.addGeofences(geofencingRequest, pendingBroadcastIntent)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                geoAlreadyInitialized = true
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                // TODO
            }
    }

    private fun getGeofenceRequest(geofence: Geofence) =
        GeofencingRequest.Builder()
            .setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER)
            .addGeofence(geofence)
            .build()

    private fun getGeofence(it: Location) = Geofence.Builder()
        .setCircularRegion(it.latitude, it.longitude, 5F)
        .setRequestId(GEOFENCE_ID)
        .setTransitionTypes(GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
        .setExpirationDuration(NEVER_EXPIRE)
        .setNotificationResponsiveness(0)
        .build()

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {...}

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? = null

    class GeofenceReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            val geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent)
            if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
                return
            }

            when (geofencingEvent.geofenceTransition) {
                GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT -> {
                    context?.showShortToast("EXIT geo blabla")
                }
                GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER -> {
                    context?.showShortToast("ENTER geo blabla")
                }
                GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_DWELL -> {
                    context?.showShortToast("dwell geo blabla")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".util.LocationForegroundService$GeofenceReceiver"/>
```

to be more precise the broadcast is never called